# Which .Net framework should my .Net Core library target?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am enjoying the "multi-target" feature of .xproj in Visual Studio 2015 which make it really easy to target multiple .Net frameworks with the same C# project. I am currently targeting .Net 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, .Net Standard 1.3 and .Net Standard 1.6 and I am packaging all the DLLs in a nuget package.

Do you think this is overkill? Should I target fewer frameworks? More?

By the way, I know xproj is eventually going away in favor of .csproj, but that's what I'm using for the time being.

Comment: Just use 4.6.2 and skip 4.6.1 and 4.6.

Comment: @JeroenHeier is right. Microsoft would soon be stopping support for .net frameworks earlier than 4.6.2

Comment: Have any of the above guys read Microsoft documentation? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/framework_faq/en-us Microsoft still supports 4.5.2/4.6/4.6.1 very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any conditional compilation yet, then you should leave only .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .NET Standard 1.3.

The reason is simple. If the package works for .NET Framework 4.5.2, it works for all .NET Framework with a bigger version. No need to target them separately.

The same applies to .NET Standard. If the package targets .NET Standard 1.3, then it can work fine for .NET Standard 1.4/1.5/1.6/2.0.

You do have to target both because .NET Framework 4.5.2 does not implement .NET Standard 1.3. Probably you don't want to target .NET Standard 1.2, as it is too limited.

Comment: Is there any downside to not providing a version built with 4.6, 4.61 and 4.6.2 if someone is using my library and targeting one of these frameworks?

Comment: @desautelsj see paragraph 2. No downside at all.

Comment: Not quite right, I guess. If you use preprocessor-directives like `#if NETSTANDARD1_2` (not sure if this is now the right one) it won't apply to `NETSTANDARD1_3` - or is there something specific like `if NETSTANDARD` or something that applies to all `net core`-frameworks?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger If your code already works for .NET Standard 1.2, then it automatically runs on 1.3 and above, and why do you need `NETSTANDARD1_3` afterward? Conditional should only be used if you want to target .NET Framework and .NET Core separately.

Comment: Say, I want to target both, .net 4.5.1 and .net standard 1.2. So there are different methods e.g. for an instance of type `Type`. I need to specify sth like `#if  NETSTANDARD1_2 bool isClass = myType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass; #elif NET451 bool isClass = myType.IsClass;` . This runs for 1.2 but won't work for 1.3. Would it?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger why not test it out? I don't think it would break on 1.3, as 1.3 supports all API of 1.2.